# Is there any other way to write this Query

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

Below query executed in **18 minutes**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM psverify_interaction_numeric_ip_address a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Xwalk_GeoLiteCity_Blocks
  WHERE startIpNum <= a.numeric_ip_address AND endIpNum >= a.numeric_ip_address 
);
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      240 |
+----------+
1 row in set (18 min 2.00 sec)
```

How can i rewrite it to optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a correlated subquery; they must be executed for every row , so they are usually terrible performers.

Instead use a join and `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)
FROM psverify_interaction_numeric_ip_address a
JOIN Xwalk_GeoLiteCity_Blocks b
  ON a.numeric_ip_address BETWEEN startIpNum AND endIpNum
```

The DISTINCT is needed in case there are multiple matching rows and you want to count each row only once.

Note also the use of BETWEEN for clarity.

Comment: hello, I wonder if a.id is not PK(or UNIQUE) and all records have same value. I think a.id should be PK (or UNIQUE) then `DISTINCT` is not required. am i right?

Answer (score 0):

you can inner join tables if you sure that the table is exist.
i am not sure, but hopefully this should work , try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM psverify_interaction_numeric_ip_address a
INNER JOIN Xwalk_GeoLiteCity_Blocks b
ON b.startIpNum <= a.numeric_ip_address AND b.endIpNum >= a.numeric_ip_address
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `psverify_interaction_numeric_ip_address.id` is PK or UNIQUE..

```
SELECT COUNT(a.id)
FROM psverify_interaction_numeric_ip_address a
INNER JOIN Xwalk_GeoLiteCity_Blocks b
  ON b.startIpNum <= a.numeric_ip_address AND b.endIpNum >= a.numeric_ip_address
```

Also you need to make :

```
`ALTER TABLE Xwalk_GeoLiteCity_Blocks
    ADD INDEX(startIpNum),
    ADD INDEX (endIpNum)
```